# 2000 ford focus wagon rear latch won't latch

Tags: ford

The rear latch opens up when I start the car and everytime I shut it opens back up!!! will not stay latched till the car is off.  I do not have a key fob so it can't be that.  Any Ideas???

Thanks Darin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electronic boot (or trunk if you're of the American persuasion) release switch has most likely failed, basically as long as the ignition is on it continually thinks you're pressing the boot release button (which is why it will stay shut when the car is off!) - This is a common issue often resulting from water ingress on these. If you take the inside cover off the boot hatch you should be able to see a connector to the release mechanism, take that off and see what state the pins are in. If they are corroded/dirty then this is your culprit!

You *might* get away with cleaning them off and re-connecting, depends how far gone it is. If cleaning it up doesn't work then you can leave it disconnected as a work around - you will have to open the boot manually on the key and the "door open" indicator light will be permanently on but you'll at least be able to drive the car!